# How to close a new windows that is created by a function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a tkinter UI which has a frame, the frame has 2 canvases, 1 canvas has a button that creates a top-level window (named top). That top-level window has a CLOSE button that closes the top window (which is easily done by top.destoy). But, I need the CLOSE button to also call a function that does something. So, since CLOSE button cannot be configured to call something() and destroy(), I set the button to call sequence() which calls something() and top.destroy().

When I run this and hit the CLOSE button, I get the error name 'top' is not defined. I know why it's happening, but I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
from tkinter import*

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.title("HOME")

f1 = Frame (window, bg="white")
f1.pack()

c1 = Canvas(f1, height=200, width=1960, bg="white")
label = Label(f1, text="Running Apps", font= "Cambria 30 bold").pack()
c1.pack(anchor=N)

r = c1.create_rectangle(400, 50, 550, 150, fill="white", activefill="black")
r2 = c1.create_rectangle(550, 50, 700, 150, fill="white", activefill="black")

c2 = tk.Canvas(f1, height=800, width=1960,  bg="white")
c2.pack(side="bottom")

def sequence():
    top.destroy()
    c1.itemconfig(r, fill="white")  #something()


def openApp1():
    c1.itemconfig(r, fill="red")
    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry("1920x1080")
    top.title("App 1")

    cvs1 = tk.Canvas(top, height="880", width="800", bg="red")
    Closebutton = Button(cvs1, text="CLOSE", command=sequence, padx="20", pady="0", justify="center", height="1", width="6", font="Cambria 20 bold",         borderwidth="7")
    cvs1.create_window(400, 600, window=Closebutton)
    label1 = Label(top, text="I am App 1", font= "Cambria 50 bold")
    label1.place(x=630, y=100)
    cvs1.pack()

button1= Button(c2, bg="red", text="App 1", command=openApp1, padx="20", pady="10", justify="center", height="3", width="10", font="Cambria 30 bold", borderwidth="10")
c2.create_window(100, 200, anchor=NW, window=button1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Otherwise we just have to imagine your code, and we'll likely not imagine your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `global top` inside `openApp1` and it will assign `TopLevel` to global variable (instead of local variable) and it will resolve problem in `sequence`

```
def openApp1():
    global top

    c1.itemconfig(r, fill="red")
    top = Toplevel()
```